# Reducer function for a nested array with conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to write a reducer function for the nested object that I have.

```
{
    "queryResult": [{
        "__typename": "Parent",
        "_id": "ABC",
        "items": [{
            "__typename": "Child",
            "_id": "123",
            "subitems": [{
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "abc",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "def",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "ghi",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "jkl",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "mno",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "pqr",
            }]
        }, {
            "__typename": "Child",
            "_id": "456",
            "subitems": [{
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "aaa",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "bbb",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "ccc",
            }, {
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "ddd",
            }]
        }, {
            "__typename": "Child",
            "_id": "789",
            "subitems": [{
                "__typename": "Grandchild",
                "_id": "eee",
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

`queryResult` can have many `Parent`s. Every `Parent` has `item`s, and every `item` has `subitem`s with their `.id`s.

How to write a reducer that would reduce the `queryResult` by taking in the `parentId` and the `itemId` and returning the array of `subitem`s? For example, for `parentId` = `ABC` and for the `itemId` = `456` I need a result that looks like:

```
 "subitems": [{
  "__typename": "Grandchild",
  "_id": "aaa",
}, {
  "__typename": "Grandchild",
  "_id": "bbb",
}, {
  "__typename": "Grandchild",
  "_id": "ccc",
}, {
  "__typename": "Grandchild",
  "_id": "ddd",
}]
```

**Note**: all the IDs are random, there is no logic there whatsoever.

Comment: what does not work with your code?

Comment: @NinaScholz  I'm failing to put that reducer together. I'm trying using .find() but it ends up in a code that is too big and ugly, and doesn't give the result I need.

Comment: @Ruham ... the provided example/task clearly presents a use case for [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)ing an exactly defined substructure within a meta structure. Neither `reduce` nor `map` nor `filter` ... etc are the right tools for this task. Array methods have each a name that hints what a method actually is going to achieve. Each method also is optimized for the tasks it is named after. Bending such methods is possible but misleading everyone else that later needs to look into such code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce `queryResult` to a map of parentId-itemId as the `key` and subitems as the `value` as follows:

```js
const data = {
  "queryResult": [
    {
      "__typename": "Parent",
      "_id": "ABC",
      "items": [
        {
          "__typename": "Child",
          "_id": "123",
          "subitems": [
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "abc" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "def" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "ghi" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "jkl" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "mno" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "pqr" }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "__typename": "Child",
          "_id": "456",
          "subitems": [
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "aaa" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "bbb" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "ccc" }, 
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "ddd" }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "__typename": "Child",
          "_id": "789",
          "subitems": [
            { "__typename": "Grandchild", "_id": "eee" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const res = data.queryResult.reduce((acc,parent) => {
  const { _id:parentId, items } = parent;
  items.forEach(({_id:itemId, subitems}) => {
    acc[`${parentId}-${itemId}`] = subitems;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: And then to isolate the needed result apply .find() on the acc ?

Comment: No, you can simply use ``res['ABC-456']``

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit early on found.

```js
const
    getSubitems = (data, id, subid) => {
        let result;
        data.some(({ _id, items }) =>
            _id === id && items.some(({ _id, subitems }) =>
                _id === subid && (result = subitems)
            )
        );
        return result;
    },
    data = { queryResult: [{ __typename: "Parent", _id: "ABC", items: [{ __typename: "Child", _id: "123", subitems: [{ __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "abc" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "def" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "ghi" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "jkl" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "mno" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "pqr" }] }, { __typename: "Child", _id: "456", subitems: [{ __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "aaa" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "bbb" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "ccc" }, { __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "ddd" }] }, { __typename: "Child", _id: "789", subitems: [{ __typename: "Grandchild", _id: "eee" }] }] }] };
    result = getSubitems(data.queryResult, 'ABC', '456');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried both yours and the answer above, and both of them work. I will accept the answer above, since it uses the reducer function, and I'm trying to learn how it works.

Comment: @Ruham ... even though the effort of trying to learn how `reduce` works is noble, the task which was ask for is more about how to identify (parent/child id) or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) exactly one sub-object within the entire data structure; there is nothing to filter for and nothing to reduce at.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sample = {
  "queryResult": [{
    "__typename": "Parent",
    "_id": "ABC",
    "items": [{
      "__typename": "Child",
      "_id": "123",
      "subitems": [{
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "abc",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "def",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "ghi",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "jkl",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "mno",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "pqr",
      }]
    }, {
      "__typename": "Child",
      "_id": "456",
      "subitems": [{
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "aaa",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "bbb",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "ccc",
      }, {
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "ddd",
      }]
    }, {
      "__typename": "Child",
      "_id": "789",
      "subitems": [{
        "__typename": "Grandchild",
        "_id": "eee",
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

function getSubItemsByParentAndItemId(arr, parentId, itemId) {
  return ((arr.find(parentItem =>

    parentItem.__typename === 'Parent'
    && parentItem._id === parentId

  ) || { items: [] }).items.find(childItem =>

    childItem.__typename === 'Child'
    && childItem._id === itemId

  ) || { subitems: [] }).subitems;
}

console.log(
  getSubItemsByParentAndItemId(sample.queryResult, 'ABC', '456')
);
console.log(
  getSubItemsByParentAndItemId(sample.queryResult, 'XYZ')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```